# R - extract elements from character string that NOT match other string

Tags: r, regex, data.table, stringr

I want to extract elements from one character string that are **not** in an other character string.

What is the fastest (vectorized?) approach?

Mock data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
             product= c("1", "1,2", "1,2,3", "4"),
             stock= c("2, 3", "1,2", "1,2", "4"))

> dt
   id product stock
1:  A       1  2, 3
2:  B     1,2   1,2
3:  C   1,2,3   1,2
4:  D       4     4
```

What I am looking for is a new variable called `new` that holds the elements from `product` that are not in `stock`.

```
> dt
   id product stock  new
1:  A       1  2, 3    1
2:  B     1,2   1,2 <NA>
3:  C   1,2,3   1,2    3
4:  D       4     4 <NA>
```

Note: it seems to be the exact opposite of `stringr::str_extract_all`, but this function doesn't have a `negate` function.

Comment: `transform(dt,new = mapply(gsub,gsub(',','|,|',dt$stock),'',dt$product,USE.NAMES = F))` from base R or use `dt%>%mutate(new = str_replace_all(product,gsub(',','|,|',stock),''))` from `tidyverse`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option by splitting the columns of interest with `strssplit`, use `setdiff` to find the elemens not in the second one.  If there are not values i.e. if the `length` iss 0, then return `NA`

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {
    x1 <- setdiff(x, y)
   if(!length(x1)) NA_character_ else x1
 }

dt[, new := do.call(Map, c(f = f1,
    unname(lapply(.SD, strsplit, ",")))), .SDcols = 2:3]
dt
#   id product stock  new
#1:  A       1  2, 3    1
#2:  B     1,2   1,2 <NA>
#3:  C   1,2,3   1,2    3
#4:  D       4     4 <NA>
```

---

Or if we need to use `str_extract_all`, the tidyverse option would be

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>% 
   mutate_at(2:3, list(newvar = ~ str_extract_all(., '\\d+'))) %>%  
   transmute(id, product, stock, new = map2(product_newvar, stock_newvar, f1))
```

Comment: Using the first approach on a subset (nrow==100000) of my actual data, I run into the following error: `Supplied 91336 items to be assigned to 91299 items of column 'new'` Is this because there might be multiple elements in `new`?

Comment: @wake_wake. It is because of the `unlist`. If there are more than one element return, either keep it as a list, to `paste` with `toString` `dt[, new := do.call(Map, c(f = f1,
     unname(lapply(.SD, strsplit, ",")))), .SDcols = 2:3]`

Comment: @wake_wake In the update, I removed the `unlist`, so it should work as it is a `list` column now

Comment: To get it unlisted, one can simple do `dt$new  <- sapply(dt$new, toString)`, I reckon.

Comment: @wake_wake Or can do this in the earlier step in function `x1 <- toString(setdiff(x, y))` and then do the earlier `unlist` version

Answer (score 1):

using only *base* and *data.table*, we loop in parallel through both columns and use `setdiff`, then add the NAs and make it an atomic vector :

```r
dt[,new:= mapply(setdiff, strsplit(product, ","), strsplit(stock, ","))]
is.na(dt$new) <- !lengths(dt$new)
dt$new <- unlist(dt$new)
dt
#>    id product stock new
#> 1:  A       1  2, 3   1
#> 2:  B     1,2   1,2  NA
#> 3:  C   1,2,3   1,2   3
#> 4:  D       4     4  NA
```

Here it is in pure *data.table* code :

```
dt[,new:= mapply(setdiff, strsplit(product, ","), strsplit(stock, ","))][
  lengths(new) == 0, new := NA][
    , new := unlist(new)]
```